# What happened to the puddle jumper on "It's Good to be King" (S8 E13)?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Simple question. What did SG-1 do with the puddle jumper they found on the planet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They used it in the Season 8 episodes ["Moebius I"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Moebius,_Part_1) and ["Moebius II"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Moebius,_Part_2).

It also shows up repaired in the novels [*Roswell*](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Roswell) and [*Moebius Squared*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Moebius_Squared).

You can find the exact details at the [wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Jumper).

Comment: I seem to recall that when they used in again in "Moebius," they suddenly started calling a "puddle jumper," even though that name had never been used on SG-1 before, and they were not in touch with Atlantis.

Comment: Perhaps it was present in a newspaper or magazine at the dinner and Daniel read it there.

Comment: Awesome. Simple question, simple answer.  I'm binge watching season 8. Knew this would be answered quickly. I accepted your answer because you were first. :-)

Comment: Moebius occured at the end of the season, and by that point Atlantis had managed to open the gate for Earth for like 3 seconds and sent a compressed data burst full of mission reports, etc, so they probably learned the name from there.  (Just recently rewatched those eps).

Answer (score 3):

### It was used to travel back in time

From "[Moebius: Part 1](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/8.19_%22Moebius_Part_1%22_Transcript)" (8.19):

> [The Puddle Jumper with the time device is flying above Earth.]
>
> INT—PUDDLE JUMPER
>
> [Daniel and O'Neill are sitting in the pilot chairs as Carter works on
> the time device. Teal'c is standing behind Daniel.]
>
> DANIEL Now remember, Jack, 3000 B.C. After Sam hooks up the power to
> the time device, think about that date and nothing else.
>
> O'NEILL This
> thing's Ancient. How's it gonna know from B.C.?
>
> CARTER Your mind is
> controlling it. The Ancient computer should be able to extrapolate
> from your concept of time.
>
> O'NEILL Well, shouldn't we test it on a
> slightly smaller leap? Like say, to 1908?
>
> CARTER Actually sir, we were
> able to determine from the data log that the technology only works in
> time jumps longer than a couple hundred years.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in stargate Atlantis episode 15

Comment: Is it the same puddle-jumper? Can you provide a source?

Comment: There were two. The first one was used by Dr Weir in stargate atlantis. The second was used by jack and Daniel in SG-1

Comment: So do you know what happened to the *specific* puddle-jumper from SG-1 S8 Ep.13? That's what's being asked here.